# Convert String Array with nulls to Int Array in Scala

Tags: string, scala

Given Array("1","2",null,"3"), convert it to an integer array replacing null with 0.

I know we can use the success/failure pattern but how can I do it with a simple case statment?

```
Array("1","2",null,"3").map({
  case null => 0
  case _ => (_:String).toInt})
```

returns `Array(<function1>,<function1>,0,<function1>)`

Comment: Your second case is returning a function  try with `case str: String => str.toInt` however, it is not common not recommended to check for `nulls` like that, you may also need to handle the error if the String wasn't a number, so I would go with `numbers.map(x => Option(x).flatMap(_.toIntOption).getOrElse(default = 0))` - Also, it is recommended to use **Lists** or any other real collection instead of plain **Arrays**

Comment: Kliao, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn every non-`Int` string into a zero without the need for a `null`-specific test.

```
Array("1","2",null,"3","w")
  .map(s => util.Try(s.toInt).getOrElse(0))
//res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 0, 3, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting only nulls and numbers, you can use `Option`:

```
Array("1","2",null,"3").map(Option(_).fold {0} {_.toInt})
```

Please note that this will throw on any element in the array which is not `int` or `null`.

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/T4xoIOxDRuOiGJSYLmr47w/1).